# Collation query error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I just started to use the new collation feature from mongoDB. I have a collection "employers" and I have a field "email" for store the employers email. I just created a new index with the collation feature by this command:
`db.employers.createIndex( { email: 1 },{ collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } } )`
In order to be able to sort with case insensitive feature. So if i have some emails like "email@example.com", "Email_second@example.com" and "another@example.com" I want to get it sorted like:

1. another@example.com
2. email@example.com
3. Email_second@example.com

But when I try to perform the query `db.getCollection('employers').find().sort({"email": 1}).collation({"locale":"en"})` to get that expected results I get the following error:

> Error: collation requires use of read commands

Some idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of Robomongo are you using? And which specific server version of MongoDB itself? The error suggests that you actually might not have issued the `.find()`. So it could be a syntax error in the context you are actually typing in.

Comment: Robomongo 3T - 1.1  
Server version 3.0.12, guess that's the problem right?

Comment: Right. Collation is not supported with 3.0.x. Like others before you you have found the error messages and that you can "create index options" ( actually does not create the new index type though ), but there is no collation available without MongoDB 3.4.x at the very least. If you want collation, then you need to upgrade.